# Разложение матрицы методом Холецкого что-то не выходит

Tags: c++

Правильно высчитывает только первый столбец, а дальше всё в кашу. Помогите

```
vector <double> holetsky (vector <vector <double>>&array, vector <double>&answers, int size) {

vector <vector <double> > arrayL (size, vector <double> (size));
vector <vector <double> > arrayLt (size, vector <double> (size));

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    double s = array[i][i];
    for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++) {
        s -= pow(arrayL[i][k], 2);
    }
    arrayL[i][i] = sqrt(s);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
        s = array[j][i];
        for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++) {
            s -= arrayL[i][k] * arrayL[j][k];
        }
        arrayL[j][i] = s / arrayL[i][i];
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        arrayLt[i][j] = arrayL[j][i];
    }
}
print(arrayL, answers, size);
print(arrayLt, answers, size);

return answers;}
```

[image: на вход подаю вот такие красивые значения из википедии]

На вход подаю вот такие красивые значения из википедии
Общее задание - решить СЛАУ этим методом, по сему не обессудьте

Answer (score 0):

Вы переписали алгоритм с инета, но неудачно индексацию массивов переписали. В этом случае нужно чуть-чуть пощупать сам алгоритм: с какими числами нужно работать.

Первый цикл

```
for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++) {
        s -= pow(arrayL[i][k], 2);    }
```

нужно было считать **до** диагонали. И второй

```
for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++) {
            s -= arrayL[i][k] * arrayL[j][k];        }
```

тоже **до** диагонали. Исправлением будет : `k < i`. Примерно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    double s = array[i][i];
    for (int k = 0; k < i ; k++) 
        s -= pow(arrayL[i][k], 2);
    arrayL[i][i] = sqrt(s);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
        s = array[j][i];
        for (int k = 0; k < i ; k++) 
            s -= arrayL[i][k] * arrayL[j][k];
        arrayL[j][i] = s / arrayL[i][i];
    }
}
```